# Separate NSMutablestring with comma

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to append two NSMutablestring, but i want to make the comma separation between them. Right now the code i use is this:

```
NSString *astring = @"This is a string";
teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[teststring appendString:astring];
NSLog(@"%@",teststring);
```

the result is :This is a stringThis is a String

i try with:

```
[teststring appendFormat:@",%@",astring];
```

but still no luck.

Please help, regards.

Comment: What does `astring` contain? What result do you get? What result do you expect?

Comment: this should work, what is the output you are getting & what you expect.

Comment: This is not an Xcode question...

Answer (score 0):

I used this and its working fine for me :

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *astring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[astring appendString:@"I am appending this string"];
[teststring appendFormat:@",%@",astring];
NSLog(@"string : %@",teststring);
```

**O/P :**  `string : ,I am appending this string`

Answer (score 0):

```
  teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
 [teststring appendString:@","];
  [teststring appendString:astring];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *astring = @"This is a string";
teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

[teststring appendString:astring];
[teststring appendString:@","];
[teststring appendString:astring];

NSLog(@"%@",teststring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World";

NSMutableString * secondstring =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

[secondstring appendString:string] 
[secondstring appendString:@","];
[secondstring appendString:string];
```

If you want to see this String

```
NSLog(@"%@",secondstring);
```